# I'm not able to write my data into file after parsing, I am constantly getting error string indices must be integer

Tags: python, json, tweets, recommendation-engine

I have stocktwits data and I am trying to convert the text files by tokenizing. I am trying to read the json format using `json.loads(line)`.

```
import json


with open(self.trainables_path + file_to_write, "w") as fp:
    for doc in enumerate(files):
        with open(self.tweets_path + doc[1]) as f:
            for line in f:
                entry = json.loads(line)
                user = list(entry.keys())[0]
                tweet = entry[user]
                fp.write(user + "_" + str(tweet['id']) + " ")
                for token in tweet['tokens']:
                    if tweet['tokens'].index(token) != len(tweet['tokens']) - 1:
                        fp.write(token + " ")
                    else:
                        fp.write(token)
                fp.write("\n")
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/dissertation/rec-sys-master/embeddings/parser.py", line 201, in <module>
    pd.convert_to_trainable()
  File "H:/dissertation/rec-sys-master/embeddings/parser.py", line 169, in convert_to_trainable
    fp.write(user + "_" + str(tweet['id']) + " ")
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The data needs to be written into the file.

Edit:
The other functions in the code are not getting executed, that is why the data format is incorrect!!

Comment: can you give us the type of the object tweet.  ( output of print(type(tweet)) )

Comment: It prints <class str>

Comment: @vellalasudhanvi then the error makes sense. If `tweet` is a string, it doesn't have an `"id"` key. You probably expected to have a dictionary, but this is not the case. Try print out `entry`, `user`, and `tweet` in your loop so that you can better understand the structure of your data.

Comment: @alec_djinn Yeah thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: The `user = list(entry.keys())[0]` line looks odd. JSON objects are unordered so getting the first name from the object is essentially getting a random name. Even if you are using a parser that is currently always giving the result you expect, this looks broken. The way you write space separated tokens is _really_ inefficient. Just use `str.join()`: `fp.write(' '.join(tweet['tokens'])`.